# How to specify archive classifier for shadowJar plugin in gradle 5+

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, shadowjar

Starting from version 5 `gradle` [changed Archive Tasks behavior](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#change_in_behavior_for_tasks_extending_abstractarchivetask_or_subtypes_zip_jar_war_ear_tar)

This breaks `shadowJar` task default behavior which doesn't create `<name>-<version>-all.jar` artifact any more.

**How to revert this behavior and create `*-all.jar`?**

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using deprecated [*classifier*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:classifier) and [*archiveName*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName) configure `shadowJar` plugin the following way:

```
shadowJar {
    archiveClassifier = 'all'
}
```

Or since [Gradle 5.1](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/release-notes.html#conveniences-for-map-properties) using [`Property`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html):

```
shadowJar {
    archiveClassifier.set('all')
}
```

See more about the issue discussion:

https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/446#issuecomment-460328699
https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/450

Comment: Intellij suggests that I can't set archiveClassifier to a string (being a property), and instead use archiveClassifier.set('')

Comment: This is a new Gradle API with `Property` value (https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html) instead of old `String`

Comment: New Gradle DSL API since version 5.1: https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/release-notes.html#conveniences-for-map-properties